# EventEmitter does't resolve correct parameter with bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, eventemitter

Working on angular2 `EventEmitter` with bootstrap modal, but whenever i pass some parameters via child component's event emitter angular does not resolve to correct parameters only in case of Bootstrap modal otherwise everything is working fine. why ? m is doing something wrong ?

calling Child component coding (parent component) -

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='#value of abc'> 
    <child-component (everySecond)="everySecond(value)"></child-component>{{view}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

child component coding -

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete_category" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header modal_header_color">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row margin_both">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row form-group text-center">
                            <span>Are you sure you want to Delete !</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)='call()' data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>  //not working
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_category">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
</button>  

  <---working ---->
    <button (click)='call()' class='btn btn-info btn-sm'>Working Button</button>  //works fine

  <---working ---->
```

plunkr for the same here http://plnkr.co/edit/2rlvpMpcTd0Gk8DelwoP?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `ChildComponent` element uses the same `id="delete_category"`. Bootstrap modal uses the first that matches the id and that's always the first `ChildComponent` with `demoInput == 1`

Changing two lines fixes it

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete_category{{demoInput}}" role="dialog">
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" 
    attr.data-target="#delete_category{{demoInput}}">
```

Also notice the added `attr.` for attribute binding.

**update**

You could use a random value for `demoInput` in `id="delete_category{{demoInput}}"`.

There seems to be no need to use the same value as in `everySecond(value)`. Only the value used in `id` and `attr.data-target` need to be the same within one `ChildComponent` while at the same time they need to be different between different `ChileComponent`s.

I would use

```
class ChildComponent {
  private static cmpId = 0; 

  // getter to make it available for binding from the template 
  // because this doesn't work with statics
  private get componentId() => ChildComponent.prototype.cmpId++;

  // I'm not sure if this ^^^ is the correct way to access static
  // fields in TypeScript.
}
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete_category{{componentId}}" role="dialog">
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" 
    attr.data-target="#delete_category{{componentId}}">
```

Comment: ohhh Man you are great, thanks its working now, thanks alot for help !

Comment: Awesome!! was working on a same issue but couldn't get it +1.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is there any to get  parameter `value` of `(everySecond)="everySecond(value)"` in the `child-component` because i don't want to send extra field just for dynamic `ID`, if i get `value` somehow than no need to send extra `demoInput` ? any idea ?

Comment: If you need the `value` for other things inside the component, you need to pass it the way you do currently.